# Замена символов через re.sub: заменить проценты на сами числа в строке: 50% -> 0.5

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Недавно задавал вопрос, как найти число с процентом (100%). Но возник другой вопрос, как, собственно, заменить его на другой символ, используя `re.sub(...)`?

У меня всё та же строка: `string 1,2,100%,50%` и такая вот функция:

```
def parse(msg,t=float):
    if msg[0].isdigit():
        k = None
        v = msg

    else:
        msg = msg.split()
        k = msg[0]
        v = msg[1]

    prc1 = re.findall(r"\d+%",v)
```

Дальше есть ещё функция поиска процента:

```
def percentage(a):
    return float(a)/100
```

После я, в функции `parse`, передаю числа в `percentage` и всё бы хорошо, но они существуют отдельно от основной строки (переменная `v`). Как мне сохранить строку и заменить все числа на уже подсчитанные в `percentage`?

На выходе должно получится: `string 1,2,1.0,0.5`

Comment: укажите то что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [154]: import re

In [155]: s = 'string 1,2,100%,50%'

In [156]: def percentage(a):
     ...:     if re.match(r'^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\s*%$', a):
     ...:         return str(float(a[:-1])/100)
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return a
     ...:

In [157]: ','.join(map(percentage, re.split('\s*,\s*|\s+', s)))
Out[157]: 'string 1,2,1.0,0.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'string 1,2,100%,50%'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)%', lambda m: str(int(m.group(1)) / 100), s)
'string 1,2,1.0,0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понятно что Вы хотите сделать, но давайте начнем с этого куска кода

```
import re
str_data="1,2,100%,50%"
list_data = str_data.split(",")
for data in list_data:
    digit_or_repl_data= re.sub(r"\d+%", "percend_data", data)
    print  digit_or_repl_data
```

проверяете если digit_or_repl_data это число то делаете что нужно с числами
если подстановка - то делаете все для процента

в таком случае Вы точно достигнете того что хотели