# Удаление пункта из текстового списка в файле, не нарушая нумерацию

Tags: python-3.x

Всем привет!
Только начал разбираться в разработке на python и попалась интересная и в то же время сложная задача для меня, которую я не могу решить.

Вот сама задача:
имеется текстовый документ, который состоит из пунктов, которые могут содержать сколько угодно подпунктов (пример - 1.1. абв; 1.2. вба; 2.4. жзи). Из этого документа могут удаляться любые пункты. Пример:

```
1.1. Пункт первый, текст.
1.2. Пункт второй, который будет полностью удален.
1.3. Пункт третий, текст.
```

При таком наивном удалении нумерация нарушится:

```
1.1. Пункт первый, текст.
1.3. Пункт третий, текст.
```

и пункт 1.3 будет следовать за пунктом 1.1.
А нужно, чтобы она не нарушалась. Т.е. после удаления пункта 1.2 пункт 1.3 должен переименоваться в '1.2. Пункт третий, текст' и текст должен выглядеть так

```
1.1. Пункт первый, текст.
1.2. Пункт третий, текст.
```

Используется Python 3.6

Comment: нужно более чётко формат файла обозначить: пункты у вас все ровно одну строчку занимают? То есть номера пунктов всегда подряд идут и  в самом начале строк находятся? Является  пример в вопросе представительным? Или ввод другой формат имеет? Какой?

Comment: пример в вопросе самый представительный, как я его вижу).  Другие варианты не рассматриваются. Сами пункты идут друг под другом (не в одну строчку в файле). Нумерация пунктов последовательная и находятся в самом начале строки всегда.

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений исправить нумерацию:

```
import re

def make_replace(index):
    def replace(m):
        nonlocal index
        s = m.group(1) + str(index)
        index += 1
        return s
    return replace

replace = make_replace(index=2)    
for line in file:
    print(re.sub(r'(^1\.)\d+', replace, line), end='')
```

Полный [пример](https://ideone.com/p8IxzQ). См. [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Можно упростить `replace()` функцию, используя `itertools.count()`:

```
replace = lambda m, i=itertools.count(index): m.group(1)+str(next(i))
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/T6XvyC).

Comment: Спасибо больше за инфу и знания!

Comment: Ох, если не сложно, можно комменты к коду написать. Самому пока сложно в написанном разобраться. Понял, что объвляется функция make_replace, но что в ней происходит не до конца усвоил.

Comment: @User: что у вас сложности вызывает? Работали с [regex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716185/23044) или [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13857/4279) или ни с тем ни с другим не знакомы?

Comment: С регулярными выражениями знаком. Я по поводу самой функции make_replace. Но перечитывая код и используя гугл, ответы находятся).

Comment: @User ссылка со словом closure должна прояснить как make_replace работает. Если есть вопросы, спрашивайте (к примеру, как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос, если не ясно как make_counter работает).